# Can the Eclipse Javascript formatter be set up for JSLint compliance?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, coding-style, jslint

I can't seem to configure the Eclipse Javascript formatting options so that it generates markup JSLint doesn't complain about - primarily whitespace settings when the "tolerate sloppy whitespace" option isn't set on JSLint. It is possible to configure this?

For example, JSLint expects function declarations to be spaced as shown:

```
function () {
}

function foo() {
}
```

but I can only get the settings to produce:

```
function () {
}

function foo () {
}
```

or

```
function() {
}

function foo() {
}
```

Alternatively is there a lightweight editor/IDE which will format my javascript code to create markup that satisfies the whims of JSLint?

Comment: You try [jshint](http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/) instead?

Comment: jslint accepts function foo () {
} for me.

Comment: JSLint is widely used.  If the formatter can't format javascript the way JSLint wants it, then the formatter is broken to the point of being worse than useless for many projects.

Comment: @epascarello I found this question because I want to use Douglas Crockford style, as enforced by JSLint. I believe it is a well thought out and well known way to make code consistent. JSHint is just a way for broken style to be accepted as valid. It's useful for some things, but not for writing code in Crockford style.

Answer (score 1):

Try [jshint-eclipse](http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/) plugin. Also see [this](http://bit.ly/MnSXha) question asked earlier.

Quote from the JSHint **[page](http://www.jshint.com/about/)** :

> JSHint is a fork of JSLint, the tool written and maintained by Douglas Crockford.
>
> The project originally started as an effort to make a more configurable version of JSLint—the one that doesn't enforce one particular coding style on its users—but then transformed into a separate static analysis tool with its own goals and ideals.

jshint-eclipse is an eclipse plugin that integrates JSHint with Eclipse.

The update site for jshint-eclipse is : 
 `http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/updates/`

**Update**

I wanted to post some snapshots to show the effect of installing this plugin on Javascript files.

#### Before

Note that the Problems view is empty.

[image: No Problems in the code]

#### After

The JSHint plugin needs some configuration to be done after installation. This is also listed on the jshint-eclipse [site](http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/install.html) :

> On a project that contains JavaScript files, open the context menu and select Properties
>   On the JSHint page, enable JSHint for this project

I did the above and enabled JSHint for *.js files like so :

[image]

After doing that with the same JS file as before, the Problem view begins showing errors:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't address the problem.  The requirement is for the editor to produce code that's acceptable for JSLint, not to use a tool that's more lenient than JSLint.